# Admin "Create New User" website assignment dropdown is blank

Tags: customer, magento-1, customer-account, websites

I just recently tried adding a new user through my Magento admin panel and the "Associate To Website" dropdown is empty.

[image]

I checked the `core_store` table in the database and it is properly populated with the correct options, but for some reason the dropdown is still empty.

[image]

I've tried clearing the cache, flushing the cache, re-indexing the entire site, and I've also searched through this community as well as through google for hours now and have seen absolutely nothing like this.

Because of this, I can't add any new users to my Magento store. There is no way for users to sign up on the front end of my site because of the type of website so this is the only way to add new users.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to solve this myself. Kind of. I updated the form coding to pull all local store views. I can now create a website user, but not an admin user. That's OK though since admin users can be created elsewhere.

Here is what I ended up doing. I edited /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php

On line 87 you will find the call for this field.
$form->getElement('website_id')->addClass('validate-website-has-store');

I simply added a custom filter to this call so it would pull my local store ID as such:

$form->getElement('website_id')->addClass('validate-website-has-store')->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteValuesForForm());

Now I have at least the "main website" store showing up in the dropdown again so I am able to add site users.